# Publish large leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to publish a rather large leaflet map from R and I get a pandoc.exe out of memory error. I was hoping for RPubs but apparently they have a 10MB limit and I am way over that. I have already reduced my shapefiles in order to some space. Any thoughts for a workaround?

The final product I am trying to make is an interactive leaflet map. Very similar to the basic leaflet example (https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/). I have gotten my map coded up and working on my machine but have not been able to publish it because its too large (at least for RPubs). I am open to any publishing options, GitHub?.

Thanks!

Comment: A bit more detail in your question would help: How are you trying to publish it/what is your expected output? What code have you written to produce your map?

Comment: You can use github pages for this I guess https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 2):

I think that the simplest method is to save it as a widget, which pushes out a full blown web page with folders of images, js, css and such. This you can host absolutely anywhere you have server access online, Godaddy is an example, or your school or work server.

Here is an example of how I extrude my web pages for this method. You can embed them anywhere.

```
library(htmlwidgets)

 map<-leaflet()%>%
    addTiles()%>%

    addPolygons(data = plotMerge,
        fillColor = ~pal(plotMerge$incomePerCapita),
        color = "#000000", 
        fillOpacity = 0.8,
        weight = 0.2,
        popup=popup)%>%
   saveWidget(map, file="map1.html", selfcontained=FALSE)
```

I have published a few in-house (testing for public release next month) using and iFrame inside of a traditional web page. You are not limited by size as long as you are willing to accept the load speeds...and the beauty of this method is you can go back into the JavaScript and tweak some of the leaflet settings not yet available in R to get more robust function and styling options.You might need to pay a few dollars for basic hosting account.

Is there a reason that this might not work for you?

Comment: This should work. I will check it out. I have also found a work around with GitPages. Thanks